# What kind of latency is expected of contract calls?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm developing a dapp and got it working well using web3 and testrpc.

My frontend is  currently pretty "chatty" with contract calls (constant methods) and everything works super fast.

I was wondering what kind of latency I should expect in the real network for simple calls? do I need to aggresively optimize my contract reads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If your dApp is running on a node (and is fully synced), then constant functions will execute similar to what you're seeing in your testing. If not, then all bets are off. Your latency will depend on the provider you're connecting to.

My best advice is once you finish development, deploy to testnet and run performance tests. Chances are if you're not running a fully synced local node, and your app is as chatty as you say, then you may be disappointed with the results. You would want to look into optimizing your reads, moving some state data out of the contract (is possible), or turning your client into a light node.